# Conditional Probability - Speaking Truth for a given condition

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> A speaks the truth 3 times out of 4, B 7 times out of 10. They both
>   assert that a white ball is drawn from a bag containing 6 balls, all
>   of different colors. Find the probability of the truth of the
>   assertion.

I had solved this problem before in the book "[How to Prepare for Quantitative Aptitude for the CAT](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=R3NKyzlTDJQC&pg=PA557&dq=speaks%20the%20truth%203%20times%20out%20of%204,%20B%207%20times%20out%20of%2010.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWgIjt5f_LAhUSI44KHa39COcQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=speaks%20the%20truth%203%20times%20out%20of%204%2C%20B%207%20times%20out%20of%2010.&f=false)" written by Mr.Arun Sharma. This is an excellent book which I uses for my studies.

> Answer given in the book is $\dfrac{21}{40}$
>
> explanation given :
>
> A is true and B is true $=\dfrac{3}{4}\times \dfrac{7}{10}=\dfrac{21}{40}$

I was also very confident of this answer as this explanation is pretty clear. We may not need to worry about the number of balls because when they both speak truth, the ball is going to be white.

I have seen many other sites are also supporting this answer (links: [pagalguy.com](http://www.pagalguy.com/discussions/official-quant-thread-for-cat-2010part-4-25058433?page=34) and many more)

> But, yesterday, this question was asked by one person in
>   [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2617#top). They have provided the answer as
>   $\dfrac{35}{36}$. It is a reliable site and hence I am puzzled by the
>   different answer.

Further searches has shown me that [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/A-speaks-the-truth-3-times-out-of-4-B-7-times-out-of-10-they-both-assert-that-a-white-ball-has-been-drawn-from-a-bag-containing-6-different-colors-What-is-the-probability-of-the-truth-of-the-assertion) has provided answer for the same question as $\dfrac{63}{64}$. Again, I found that the [book written by Mr.Prem Kumar](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wGpEQxT_1ssC&pg=SA26-PA10&lpg=SA26-PA10&dq=speaks%20the%20truth%203%20times%20out%20of%204,%20B%207%20times%20out%20of%2010.&source=bl&ots=Ax8pO3lNxk&sig=fdUe2mlLCSas6vm7r9Udga51GXY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLrNewlf_LAhWCTI4KHcbLAaMQ6AEIMTAF#v=onepage&q=speaks%20the%20truth%203%20times%20out%20of%204%2C%20B%207%20times%20out%20of%2010.&f=false) uses Baye's theorem for the same problem and derives the answer as $\dfrac{7}{12}$ (see their answer in page 26.19). There are many sites whish supports this answer (links: Questiion 28 in [nssfmu.blogspot.in](http://nssfmu.blogspot.in), [ymg.weiproject.com](http://ymg.weiproject.com/forums/topic/my-maths-test-q3))

All these explanations are clear. But, totally confused about different sites and books gives different answers.

Please help to understand what is the right answer and right method.

Comment: IMO some sources are misinterpreting the question, some have ignored that a liar need not necessarily say "white", and Quora has an arithmetic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ Both can be speaking the truth when they say "white", or
$(b)$ both may be **specifically** lying by saying "white" ($1\;of\;5$ possiblities) when it is not white.

$(a):Pr = \dfrac16\dfrac34\dfrac7{10} = \dfrac{21}{240}= \dfrac{35}{400}$

$(b): Pr = \left[\dfrac56\right]\left[\dfrac15\cdot\dfrac14\right]\left[\dfrac15\cdot\dfrac3{10}\right]= \dfrac1{400}$

$Pr(\;assertion\; is\; true) =\dfrac{35}{35+1}$

Note that the question **does not** state that both speak the truth, only that both said "white".

Comment: What if they lie by saying the name of a color that doesn't exist in the bag? You've assumed they won't in your answer, which is a very strong assumption.

Comment: @true blue anil, you have cleared my doubt which is really hellpful for my preparation. so the answer given at http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2617#top is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @ sanketalekar, I think your argument is not correct because their probability of telling a lie is considered.

Comment: @Kiran no. Probability of telling a lie is 1/4 and 3/10. But *which* lie? We don't know the probability distribution or sample space of their lies (for all we know they could be lying by only saying the balls are black or blue, and not mentioning any other color while lying)

Comment: @sanketalekar: To me it seems a reasonable assumption that it is known what colors are there, and lies will also lie within that spectrum. Anyway, without that assumption, no answer is possible.

Comment: @trueblueanil Exactly. So my advice is add that to your answer to make it complete :), that's all.

Comment: @Kiran: Study the matching answers carefully, to satisfy yourself whether the approach is essentially the same.

Comment: @sure, thanks for the advice. This is a lesson for me that even most reputed books can make errors and I have to consider this in my preparation. Most importantly, as you said, I have to be clear in the approach. thanks again.

Comment: Why you have done (1/5)(1/4)  . The probability of saying false should be [1-(3/4)]. And why the same logic is not applied when he says truth.

Comment: @user123733: $1-3/4 = 1/4$ is probability of lying. $(1/5)(1/4)$ is the probability of specifically saying "white" while lying.

Answer (score 0):

There are several dozen different ways of reading the problem, that give rise to dozens of distinct answers.

First off, by 'speak the truth' we normally mean that they report the actual color, but there are two common interpretations of *not* speaking the truth:

- The answer they give is *guaranteed* to be incorrect - they are chosing from one of the five remaining colors, or
- They are chosing at random from *all six* colors, and might by chance still pick the right one.

The other point of ambiguity is interpreting exactly what "the assertion" refers to, and what *exactly* "They both assert that a white ball is drawn from a bag containing 6 balls" means. There are several dozen ways to interpret this, of which here are a few of the variables:

- Are we asserting that:

  - A and B actually make those statements?
  - A and B's statements are correct?
  - A and B's statements are correct given that they made them?
  - A and B made those statements given that they are correct?
- Are A and B asserting that:

  - A white ball is drawn?
  - A white ball is drawn from a bag?
  - A white ball is drawn from a bag containing six balls?
  - A white ball is drawn from a bag containing six balls, all different colors?

The issue here is that the question's wording is *fundamentally ambiguous*, and the interpretation thereof up to the whim of the test designer.

Unfortunately, this is a very common flaw with problems used in aptitude testing. Aptitude tests generally contain only problems that can be solved without mathematical training, but they are also designed to have a very flat score distribution.

As a result, any clear and unambiguous problems end up solved correctly by the vast majority of the test takers. These problems are then cut since they are 'too easy'. Only vague and ambiguous problems stick around, because despite needing "only" simple mathematical reasoning, they are the only ones consistently found to be 'difficult' when the test scores are analyzed.

TLDR: Quantitative aptitude tests are a scam.